# is it possible to change resources at running time from the code

Tags: android

i have a application for listing student mark and name that is stored in raw resources ..res/raw

Can i change it from the code

any idea

regards,
Kariyachan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

res/raw is read only once the app is compiled - the only way would be to move the data from the res/raw folder to another location - an sqlite maybe best for changing data.

Comment: thanks for quick reply  ,then  suppose i have a application that read file from the user how can i implement that. is der any better way to do that i read data from the memory .application such as pdf reader

Comment: @Kariyachan sorry but I don't really under stand your reply - you need to decide which format you want to work with first, then how you want to handle the data. If you were originally going to use a xml or csv file in the res/raw you still could include it there, but on first run your app would need to copy it to the data/app directory then you could work with the file there. Or you could get the entries and enter them into a DB. You could get a file off the SD card and process it.